# Ubuntu 16.04 running on a Dell 1950 server 16GB RAM 140GB HDD CPU @ 2% Mem @9% runs slow

Tags: server, dell, performance

I'm working on making a mining rig for Zcash/Bitcoin ... I got myself a Dell PowerEdge 1950 III server, I know I should be running Ubuntu server on it but I can't live without the GUI ... not good enough with the command line yet. Is there anything I can do to make this system go faster or would be causing it to go incredibly slow.

Comment: Learn to live without GUI on a server. If you don’t know how to do something, just google it.

Comment: You are aware that you need to invest in a proper ASIC and join a pool for profitable Bitcoin mining, right?

Comment: I did join a pool but unsure of what you mean by getting an ASIC?

Comment: I am doing CPU mining... will I still need an ASIC?

Comment: The CPU runs at 2% and is only using 8% memory. Moving things around on the screen lags and so does moving from window to window. Could this be a graphics problem? How can I check?

Comment: @Trenton Maybe, you haven’t told us anything about graphics… One more reason to get rid of GUI completely when aiming to get a high performance.

Answer (score 0):

The issue you are implying is you don't have a GPU and so graphical things like the Ubuntu desktop environment aren't rendered by the GPU but instead on the CPU and the CPU doesn't handle things like that unless it has a built-in GPU like the Intel HD 4000 series.